# FFmpeg - add .mov video overlay looping on top of input video till the end

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

So i have 2 files.

```
C:\video_resized.mp4

C:\videoOverlay.mov
```

"C:\videoOverlay.mov" needs to go on top of "C:\video_resized.mp4" and at the same time it needs to loop until the end of "C:\video_resized.mp4"

I tried to use

```
"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\video_resized.mp4" -i "C:\videoOverlay.mov" -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" "C:\video_watermarked.mp4"
```

That works fine for adding the overlay, but i have no idea on how to have the overlay looping until the end of the first video.

Comment: you mean that the duration of videoOverlay.mov is shorter and you want it to play in a loop? Maybe you can create a new video by concatenating  videoOverlay.mov to itself until both videos have the same duration.

Comment: my video has a transparent background, concatenating it atleast from my experience takes transparency away but i gotta double check that

Comment: Yeah after looping it to a new file it loses transparency and the background is black.